# App permissions do not apply and the Auth Dialog does not reflect them

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following problem, thanks in advance for any help regarding this issue.

I configured my application in `Apps > [NAME-OF-THE-APP] > Permissions` ([https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP-ID]/permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/%5BAPP-ID%5D/permissions)) to request "publish_actions", when user use the application for the first time, as seen in the picture below...

[image: http://f.cl.ly/items/0O0V0s3g3Y3z0t1Z2P2p/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-26%20at%208.36.32%20AM.png]

The problem is that the Auth Dialog does not reflect this configuration, and therefore does not ask for permission to "publish_actions"...

[image: http://f.cl.ly/items/12082g323w182E0U1Y05/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-26%20at%208.36.49%20AM.png]

I tried with different "User & Friends Permissions" and "Extended Permissions" but the Auth Dialog remains always the same.

I use the JavaScript SDK, here's the code, and I'm trying to access my app within the Canvas.

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId:'398977410174164',status:true,cookie:true,xfbml:true});

    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('UserID, ' + FB.getAuthResponse()['userID'] + '.');
            console.log('Access token, ' + FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'] + '.');
        });
    }

    function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                testAPI();
            } else {
                // cancelled
            }
        });
    }

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if(response.status === 'connected'){
            var signedRequest = response.authResponse.signedRequest;
        }else if(response.status === 'not_authorized'){
            login();
        }else{
            login();
        }
    });
};

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>
```

Thanks again for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[For the xth time:]*

These setting apply **only** to login from the app center. (And they also *used* to affect login via Authenticaed Referrals, which are now deprecated.)

Whenever you’re triggering the login **yourself** however (as you are doing with your FB.login call) – you have to specify the permissions there and then, via the `scope` parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, sorry for the apparently repetitive questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside your login() function:

```
function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            testAPI();
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    }, {scope:'publish_actions'});
}
```